# Trying to order lists in rails admin tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to order each of my admin tables so they displayed by most recent first.

As an example, I'd like to order the supplier table by created_at DESC - this will mean that the most recent supplier is displayed at the top.

Currently in views/admin/suppliers/index.html.haml:

```
%thead
    %tr
      %th= sort_link(@search, :name, 'ID')
      %th= sort_link(@search, :name, 'Name')
      %th= sort_link(@search, :category, 'Category')
      %th= sort_link(@search, :region, 'Region')
      %th Review Count
      %th Average rating
      %th Claimed?
      %th Owner
      %th
      %th
      %th
  %tbody
    = render @suppliers
```

in views/admin/suppliers/_supplier.html.haml:

```
%tr
  %td= supplier.id
  %td= supplier.name
  %td= supplier.category_name
  %td= supplier.region_name
  %td= supplier.review_count
  %td= supplier.average_overall_rating
  %td= supplier_claimed_label(supplier.owned?)
```

and in my controllers/admin/suppliers_controller.rb :

```
def index
    @search    = Supplier.search(params[:q], :order => params[:sort] || "created_at DESC")
    @suppliers = @search.result
  end
```

But this doesn't seem to be doing it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a gem for that search method? If not, could you show the method definition for it, it would be in the Supplier model.

Comment: Yes, it's using Ransack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure on the specifics of Ransack other than what I can read in the documentation, but the return of `result` is a ActiveRecord relation, so you can add extra ActiveRecord methods to that which will affect your results like so...

```
def index
    @search    = Supplier.search(params[:q])
    @suppliers = @search.result.order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

I can't test this obviously as I don't have a project with this gem, but this should work.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Not sure how bounties work as I've never answered a question with one before, but I don't seem to have been awarded it.

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me do it in the first 24 hours and then I forgot. Thanks for the reminder...